# Access field contents length 255 characters

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

I have an SQL table linked in MS Access which contains a number of short text fields that are limited to 255 characters. This table is updated from an Access form.

I was informed that when data is extracted from the table one of the fields is excessively long based on the contents.

I investigated and ran this query:

```
SELECT [dbo_NCR User Input].ImpactGrade, Len([impactgrade]) AS length
FROM [dbo_NCR User Input];
```

...which showed that regardless of the contents, the field length was 255 characters:

[image: Query Results]

Has anyone experienced this issue and if so how can it be resolved to remove the additional characters from the field?

Comment: Are you saying that more than 255 characters are being stored in a SQL Server table?

Comment: Hi Andy, no that's not happening. The text entered into the SQL table via the access form is less than 255 characters but when the query is run on the table the result shows the field contents to be 255 characters.

Comment: What are the data types of the fields in SQL Server? Please also refer to it as SQL Server table, if that is the case, not just SQL table. [Every table is a SQL table.]

Comment: all the fields are 'Short Text' and have a field size of 255

Comment: Short Text is an Access data type, not a SQL Server one.

Answer (score 1):

If the data type of the field in the SQL Server table is `CHAR(255)` as opposed to `VARCHAR(255)`, then 255 bytes are always allocated for the field value, regardless of the true length of the content.

Conversely, `VARCHAR(255)` only allocates the bytes required to store the content of the field (+2 bytes), up to the given maximum.

Comment: CHAR vs VARCHAR is the first thing to eliminate for sure.